# Integral $\int_0^L x^m\cdot \sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})\cdot \sin(\frac{p\pi x}{L})dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to evaluate this integral 
$$\int_{0}^{L} x^m\cdot \sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})\cdot \sin(\frac{p\pi x}{L}) dx,$$

where $m, n, p$ are positive integers and $L$ is a positive real number.

Wolfram|Alpha gave me a result with Hypergeometric function but I'm sure there must be a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let us apply the following well knownn trigonometric formula:
$$
\sin{\alpha}\sin{\beta} = \frac{1}{2}\cos(\alpha - \beta)-\frac{1}{2}\cos(\alpha + \beta).
$$

Then,

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^Lx^m\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)\sin\left(\frac{p\pi x}{L}\right)dx &= \\ 
&= \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^Lx^m\cos\left(\frac{(n-p)\pi x}{L}\right)dx - 
\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^Lx^m\cos\left(\frac{(n+p)\pi x}{L}\right)dx = \\
&=\frac{1}{2}I(m, n-p) - \frac{1}{2}I(m, n+p), 
\end{aligned}
$$

where
$$
I(m, k) = \int_{0}^Lx^m\cos\left(\frac{k\pi x}{L}\right)dx.
$$

The latter integral can be calculated by using the integration by parts
$$
\begin{aligned}
I(m, k) &= \int_{0}^Lx^m\cos\left(\frac{k\pi x}{L}\right)dx = \\
&= \frac{L}{\pi k}\int_{0}^Lx^md\sin\left(\frac{k\pi x}{L}\right) = \\
& = \frac{L}{\pi k}\left(\left.x^m\sin\left(\frac{k\pi x}{L}\right)\right|_0^L - m\int_0^Lx^{m-1}\sin\left(\frac{k\pi x}{L}\right)dx \right) = \\
&= \frac{L^2m}{\pi^2 k^2}\int_0^Lx^{m-1}d\cos\left(\frac{k\pi x}{L}\right) = \\
&=  \frac{L^2m}{\pi^2 k^2}\left(\left.x^{m-1}\cos\left(\frac{k\pi x}{L}\right)\right|_0^L-(m-1)\int_0^Lx^{m-2}\cos\left(\frac{k\pi x}{L}\right)dx\right) = \\
&=\frac{L^2m}{\pi^2 k^2}\left(L^{m-1}(-1)^k-(m-1)I(m-2, k)\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Now, we have a recurrent formula for integrals.

Several cases have to be considered separately:

1) $n = \pm p$

2) $m = 2q-1$ ($m$ is odd)

3) $m = 2q$ ($m$ is even)

Comment: I was thinking this, thanks. Since m is a positive integer we can repeat the process until I(0,k) and that's just antiderivative of cos.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry again for pen n paper solution and an incomplete one. Assuming n,n,p and L are positive integers
[image: Assuming n,n,p and L are positive integers]

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the hypergeometric functions come for the definite integral.

For the antiderivative, transform the product of sines by the sum of two cosines to face two integrals looking like
$$\int x^m\, \cos\left(\frac{q\pi x}{L}\right)\, dx$$ which can express in terms of the incomplete gamma function or, better, the exponential integral function
$$\int x^m\, \cos\left(\frac{q\pi x}{L}\right)\, dx=-\frac{1}{2} x^{m+1} \left(E_{-m}\left(-i\frac{ q\pi  
   x}{L}\right)+E_{-m}\left(i\frac{ q\pi   x}{L}\right)\right)$$

Comment: Is evaluating exponential integral easier than the original?

Comment: @MuratGüven. Well, you asked for other formulations. As said, the antiderivative express in terms of the incomplete gamma function or the exponential integral function. If you are concerned by numerical performance, the last is the best (imho).